# Blocking behavior of PyGTK's main loop

Tags: python, callback, pygtk

My intention was to use pyGTK's main loop to create a function that blocks while it waits for the user's input. The problem I've encountered is best explained in code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import gtk

def test():
    retval = True
    def cb(widget):
        retval = False
        gtk.main_quit()

    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    button = gtk.Button("Test")
    button.connect("clicked", cb)
    button.show()
    window.add(button)
    window.show()

    gtk.main()
    return retval

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print test() # prints True when the button is clicked
```

It seems that the exact order of instructions (change value of `retval`, *then* exit main loop) isn't being followed here.

Is there any way around this, or is this just bad design on my part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that when python sees `foo = bar` as the first reference to `foo` in a function it assumes that it is a local variable. In python3k you can get around this by using the [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) keyword. For 2.x you can wrap your retval in a list so that you aren't directly assigning to it.

```
retval = [True]
def cb(widget):
    retval[0] = False
    gtk.main_quit()
...
return retval[0]
```

not really an elegant solution, hence the addition of nonlocal in 3.x ([PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/#rationale))

Comment: Indeed that fixed it, thanks! The PEP you linked to also provides another solution (using a 'Namespace' class). I'll have to decide which is less ugly :P

Answer (score 3):

This is the dialog pattern. Use a gtk.Dialog. [Dialog.run()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkdialog.html#method-gtkdialog--run) blocks exactly how you need it to, and returns the dialog's return code.